# Google Play app icons are not showing on Careers site

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On [my Careers page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/dj), the icons for all my Android apps are broken:

[image: missing image careers]

It looks like the URLs to the images are invalid, e.g.

https://play.google.com/static/client/images/1282043220-favicon.ico

Comment: Looks like they moved it to some kind of CDN, probably to save some bandwidth: https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market_images/web/favicon.ico

Answer (score 4):

This only affected projects that were imported into the system before Google changed the favicon url. I went ahead and added a script to update those old urls to the new one, and it should show up on the site shortly.

New Google Play projects imported into the site shouldn't have this issue.